# Definition of "convertible to" used in ISO C++ library clauses

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The response of [LWG 484](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#484) shows "convertible" is "well-defined in the core". Which clauses does it refer to?

I have this question because currently the requirements of `is_convertible` are carefully defined in [[meta.rel]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#rel-5), which are not in the core. Although it has clearly noted the technical benefits, the coexistence with other styles seems confusing in the overall library clauses. So there are more questions about the general use.

- Do the meaning of requirements implied by `is_convertible` and the "convertible to" (without the code font) wording in the library clauses exactly the same?
- If true, why both are used?
- If not, is there any guideline or rationale to differentiate these subtle use cases?

Answer (score 0):

*Convertible to* refers to something that can be a result of a *standard conversion sequence* defined in [[conv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv) and since `is_convertible` is defined in terms of what conversion the core language allows during the copy-initialization of a return value, I don't see any difference.

Edit: *Implicit conversion sequence* might be another useful term not mentioned in the question. It is defined in [[over.best.ics]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics)

Answer (score 0):

The "'convertible' is well-defined in core" statement was added at some point between 2004 and 2009, though that page doesn't say exactly when. So I looked at the C++03 and C++11 standards, and it appears that neither actually has a definition of the term "convertible". However, I think we can infer that "convertible" is generally intended to mean "implicitly convertible", and the meaning of "implicitly convertible" is given by [conv] ([conv.general] in newer editions of the standard).

For example C++11 [conv]/3 says:

> An expression `e` can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). ...

However, it should be noted that the definition of "implicitly converted" uses an *expression*, not a type, as the source, whereas "convertible to" in the library sometimes has a type as the source. In that case, "`T` is convertible to `U`" should be interpreted as "all expressions of type `T` can be implicitly converted to type `U`".

There are other plausible meanings of "convertible", for example:

- The first sentence of [expr.static.cast] says "The result of the expression `static_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`". This is more powerful than an implicit conversion. It can, for example, convert `void*` to `int*`, or from an enum type to an integral type.
- The sections of the C++ standard that specify the behaviour of `(T)` *cast-expression* and `T` `(` *expression-list*(opt) `)` are titled "Explicit type conversion (cast notation)" and "Explicit type conversion (functional notation)". These conversions are much more powerful than implicit conversions; they can call explicit constructors and explicit conversion operators, and even perform `static_cast`s, `reinterpret_cast`s, and `const_cast`s (and even bypass access control in some cases).

But if we look at how the term "convertible" is actually used in the standard, it seems that it must be intended to mean "implicitly convertible". For example, C++11 [allocator.uses.trait]/1 says:

> *Remark:* automatically detects whether `T` has a nested `allocator_type` that is convertible from `Alloc`. Meets the BinaryTypeTrait requirements (20.9.1). The implementation shall provide a definition
> that is derived from `true_type` if a type `T::allocator_type` exists and `is_convertible<Alloc, T::allocator_type>::value != false`, otherwise it shall be derived from `false_type`. [...]

Evidently the intent here was that "convertible" means the same thing as what `is_convertible` tests for, that is, implicit convertibility (with a caveat that will be discussed below).

Another example is that in C++11 [container.requirements.general], Table 96, it is stated that for a container `X`, the type `X::iterator` shall be "convertible to `X::const_iterator`". The general understanding of this is that it means implicitly convertible, *i.e.*, this is well-formed:

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
}
```

Imagine if you had to use a cast, or even just direct-initialization notation, to perform this conversion. Could LWG have meant to use the word "convertible" to with a meaning that would make such an implementation conforming? It seems very doubtful.

---

Wait, does "convertible to" have the same meaning as what the standard type trait `std::is_convertible` tests for? Assuming that "convertible to" means "implicitly convertible to" with the caveat above, strictly speaking, no, because there is the edge case where `std::is_convertible<void, void>::value` is true but `void` is not implicitly convertible to itself (since the definition of a `void` variable is ill-formed). I think this is the only edge case (also including the other 15 variations involving cv-qualified `void`), although I'm not 100% sure about that.

However, this doesn't explain why `std::is_convertible` is sometimes used in the library specification. Actually, it is only used once in C++11 (other than in its own definition), namely in [allocator.uses.trait]/1, and there, it doesn't seem that there is any intent for it to mean anything other than "implicitly convertible", since it is irrelevant what happens when `Alloc` is void (as it is mentioned elsewhere that non-class types are not permitted as allocator types). The fact that `std::is_convertible` is even mentioned here seems like it's just a mild case of an implementation detail leaking into the specification. This is probably also the case for most other mentions that appear in newer editions of the standard.

---

C++20 introduced a concept called `std::convertible_to`, where `std::convertible_to<From, To>` is only modelled if

- `From` is implicitly convertible to `To`, and
- `static_cast<To>(e)` is well-formed, where `e` has type `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<From>` (*i.e.*, `From` is also *explicitly* convertible to `To` via `static_cast`), and
- some other requirements hold, which I won't get into here.

It's reasonable to ask whether some uses of "convertible to" actually mean `std::convertible_to`, given the similar names, and other considerations. In particular, the one mentioned by LWG 484 itself. C++20 [input.iterators] Table 85 states that if `X` meets the *Cpp17InputIterator* requirements for the value type `T`, then `*a` must be "convertible to `T`", where `a` has type `X` or `const X`.

This is almost certainly another case where "convertible to", as used in the library specification, implies "implicitly convertible to", but I think that it also *should* imply "explicitly convertible to", where the implicit and explicit conversions give the same results. We can construct pathological iterator types for which they don't. See [this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/e6WxexrY9) for an example.

I think both users and standard library implementers should feel free to assume that if a function accepts input iterators, it can assume that explicit conversions via `static_cast` or direct-initialization notation from `*a` to `T` can be used with the same result as implicit conversions. (Such explicit conversions may, for example, be used when calling function templates, if we want the deduced type of the function template specialization's argument to be `T&` or `const T&` and not some other `U&` or `const U&` where `U` is the actual type of `*a`.) In other words, I think "convertible to" in the input iterator requirements really means something like `std::convertible_to`, not `std::is_convertible_v`. I would be surprised if standard library implementations truly only relied on implicit convertibility in this case, and not both implicit and explicit convertibility (with the two being equivalent). (They *can* implement the library in an extremely careful way that only uses implicit conversions in cases where one would normally use an explicit conversion, but I'm not sure if they actually do. And even if they are indeed that clever, it is not reasonable to expect the same from anyone who is not a standard library implementer.)

But that's an issue for LWG to resolve. Notice that LWG 484 was reopened in 2009 and remains open to this day. It's probably a lot of work to go through all the uses of "convertible to" and "convertible from" and determine which ones should mean "implicitly convertible to" and "implicitly convertible from" and which ones should mean `std::convertible_to` (as well as if any uses of "implicitly convertible to" need to be changed to `std::convertible_to`).